# Not sure whether to include random effect that's related to fixed effects

Tags: random-effects-model, mixed-model

I'm unsure about whether I need to include a random effect in a mixed effects model that I'm running, as the fixed effects are related to this random effect.

I'm looking at how the intelligibility of an accent relates to the similarity of the talker and listeners' accents. I have two listener groups who heard three different accents, and for each listener I have two measures of the similarity of their speech to the three accents they heard, and also the intelligibility of the three accents. The two similarity measures are correlated, but that's another matter!

The model I'm currently working with is this:

```
 model<-lmer(accuracy~similarity_1*similarity_2*Group+(1|listener), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

but I'm not sure whether I should also include accent as a random effect:

```
 model<-lmer(accuracy~similarity_1*similarity_2*Group+(1|Accent)+(1|listener), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

As the similarity of the accent to the listener's speech is pretty much a measure of the accent (i.e.: listeners from London's accents are more similar to the London accent than to the non-native accent presented), I'm not sure whether this already accounts for the baseline variance in the different accents. Including accent as a random effect has very little effect for one group where the intelligibility scores cluster into distinct groups for the accents, but it has a very large effect for one group where the intelligibility of the accents overlaps more.

What would be the best choice? I'm really rather confused!